# Options when auto-recompiling xmonad

Tags: xmonad

Is there a way to pass options to `xmonad --recompile`? I'm interested in the following:

- Produce a dynamically linked executable
- Change the path / name of the generated executable

or, in general, pass other options to the compiler.